# php check if all values from one two dimensional array are in another two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a two, two dimensional arrayw like this. They are dynamicly created so they can have different numbers of arrays inside.

```
$userInput['shops'] = Array 
(
    [0] => Array 
    (
        [id] => 9
    )
)
```

and another that look like this:

```
$userShops = Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 9
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 10
    )
)
```

First array is something that i receve from post, ids of selected shops. Second array shows all ids of shops that user have. How can i test if all values from userInput can be found in array userShops? I use this for validation so i need to see if all values from post matches the real values for user.

I have tried to do it like this but i receve oknot as result, so i think this should be constructed differently, maybe to somehow count matches...You should ignore my code because i think this is bad approach...In short i need to check if all values from first array can be found in second, if not than show an error.

```
if(isset($userInput['shops']) && is_array($userInput['shops'])){
    foreach($userInput['shops'] as $input){
        foreach($userShops as $userShop){
            if(in_array($input, $userShop)){
                print_r('ok');
            }
            else {
                print_r('not'); or show validation error
            }
        }
    }
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
function flatten(array $data) {
    return array_map(function(array $element) {
        return $element['id'];
    }, $data);
}

$user = flatten($userInput['shops']);
$shops = flatten($userShops);

$isCovered = empty(array_diff($user, $shops));
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I have just flattened the second array, and i asked in foreach if values from post are in_array(), second array. array_diff showed some wierd error :)